# PostgreSQL - CREATE EXTENSION without warning

Tags: postgresql

In my migration script I am installing `unaccent` extension.

I use:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS unaccent;
```

It runs fine, but it spawns warning if the extension is already installed.

```
Warnings:
extension "unaccent" already exists, skipping
```

The script runs fine, but it breaks my flyway migration because the message is returned from migration. Is there any way how to check if the extension is already installed and avoid the message.

Comment: Maybe a check against [`pg_extension`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-extension.html) to see if it's installed first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to omit those warnings, you need to tune down `client_min_messages = ERROR`